# OpenEdge AppServer Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, openedge, progress-4gl

I would like to use the Spring security framework that OpenEdge has bundled with REST services. I have a table called `os_user` for users and would like to use this to validate credentials.

Does anyone know how to do this or have any experience with the Spring framework in OpenEdge?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/pasoe-admin/enabling-spring-security-for-apsv-and-soap-web-a.html

Comment: Yes. There's options there to enable a security model, but no obvious implementation method to use a database to authenticate users against.

Comment: Yes, I read it, not very enlightening... If I look into it I will post...

Comment: This entry in the knowledgebase might be of more help: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/What-are-the-basic-steps-to-authenticate-REST-clients-against-the-OpenEdge-database-User-table

Comment: @Jensd Thats exactly what i was looking for - The article explained what i needed to do! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the article posted by Jensd (http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/What-are-the-basic-steps-to-authenticate-REST-clients-against-the-OpenEdge-database-User-table) Following the steps there allowed me to create a custom class, which then runs as part of the spring authentication.

Implementing the appSecurity-form-oerealm option for Progress, under the OERealmUserDetails section has an XML property node with a name of "realmClass". In this property you specify the name of your custom class, which tells the spring framework to run this to validate credentials.

A ValidateUser method and ValidatePassword method must be in this class. These methods allow you to run any OE code you like to access your database and validate user credentials.

*Note that this method of authentication is for older "Classic" AppServers, and an older version of spring. Progress have now released PAS for OpenEdge which works differently.